# GA4 Data Export to BigQuery has suddenly stopped

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-4

GA4 data export to BigQuery suddenly stopped a few days ago.
BQ is still linked to GA4 and GA4 is capturing data. No export limit has been reached as well.
Please note that the BQ is in a sandbox project. could this be related?

Answer (score 0):

Of course , sand box projects only support 10 GB of storage support monthly and after that exporting stopped untill the refersh at the start of the new month.